# What happens when a Dragonfire Adept with a template uses Humanshape?

Tags: house-rules, dnd-3e

If a Dragonfire Adept has the Draconic template (LA+1) then uses Humanshape, does that affect his alternate forms in any way? Would that allow him to apply his template to his other forms, or perhaps have access to certain other forms with an equivalent LA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, *humanoid shape* is simply [Change Shape](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#changeShape) to any [humanoid](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#humanoidType) form. It never references your native type anywhere in the invocation, so it doesn’t matter if you’re Dragon, Humanoid, or Ooze, you wind up a Humanoid after using it.

As for Change Shape’s effect...

> The creature retains the type and subtype of its original form. It gains the size of its new form.

Thus, you keep the Dragonblooded subtype from Draconic.

> The creature loses the natural weapons and movement modes of its original form, as well as any extraordinary special attacks of its original form not derived from class levels (such as the barbarian’s rage class feature).

But you lose the claws.

> The creature retains all other special attacks and qualities of its original form, except for breath weapons and gaze attacks.

So you keep the darkvision, low-light vision, the bonus on saves vs. magic sleep effects and paralysis, and the bonus on Intimidate and Spot.

> The creature retains the ability scores of its original form.

And you keep the ability score bonuses.

Also, point of interest, Draconic creatures don’t change to Dragon type, they just get the Dragonblooded subtype. They’re not *very* dragon-y to begin with. And Draconic is a pretty poor choice for a dragonfire adept.

Comment: Ah. Well, at least it'll still let me disguise myself as a non-draconic version of my race either way.

Comment: @Cobalt Draconic shouldn’t be *exceptionally* noticeable, it represents a fairly faint trace of dragon blood.